# In C# what is the default value of the bytes when creating a new byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays

The answer to this question has eluded my search.

When I do this:

```
  var authToken = new byte[16];
```

What is the value of authToken[0]?

Is it null or zero?

Comment: Why not write a line of code and use the debugger?

Comment: I think it's warning or error at complie time. You should give it a try. If it's a local variable.

Comment: A `byte` cannot be `null`.

Comment: `byte b = default(byte)`

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt because that just tells me on my PC in that particular point in time, it was zero. It doesn't guarantee that it would be zero in production.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default value is 0

For more information about default values:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

Comment: And following the link, critically, there is this text: Remember that using uninitialized variables in C# is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to set empty array for Auto-Implemented Properties, you can do that way.

```
public byte[] Attachement { get; set; } = Array.Empty<byte>();
```

So when you create new class that this property belongs to, if it is empty, it will be store like `0x`

Answer (score 2):

From [`Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to **zero**, and
>   reference elements are set to **null**.

Since [`byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx) represents integer values from `0` to `255`, all elements are set to `0` in your `authToken` array.