# Encrypt using AES 256 Mode-CBC IV(0)

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

[image]I am looking for some help in doing AES 256 bit encryption with Mode as CBC and IV as (16 byte) `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`.

Basically I want to replicate what's done on [this link](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/). All keys will be in hex. Following is what i have copied from some other link.

Couple of questions in below solution:

1. How can i make IV key all zero's?
2. How can I tell that all my keys are in hex and out put has to be in hex as well?

```
public static String Encrypt(String plainText, String key)
{
    var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
}

static RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String secretKey)
{
    var keyBytes = new byte[16];
    var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);
    Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
    return new RijndaelManaged
    {
        Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        KeySize = 128,
        BlockSize = 128,
        Key = keyBytes,
        IV = keyBytes

    };
}

static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
{
    return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()
        .TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: You mean `IV = new byte[16]` and `KeySize = 256`?

Comment: yes sir and its value has to be all zero's

Comment: Yes, the default value of byte array is all zero: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506274/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-default-value-of-the-bytes-when-creating-a-new-byte-array

Comment: yes key size is 256 bits

Comment: that's my key d651b30f-9c4c-4be0-83b8-2d7816256f64

Comment: That's not hex. `-` is not a valid hex character

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how i am able to do it online. please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75494/discussion-between-amit-and-artjom-b).

Comment: @Amit That is a Guid

Answer (score 2):

Two simple methods to encrypt and decrypt compatible with the linked page:

```
public static byte[] HexToBytes(string str, string separator = " ")
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    if (separator == null)
    {
        separator = string.Empty;
    }

    if (str == string.Empty)
    {
        return new byte[0];
    }

    int stride = 2 + separator.Length;

    if ((str.Length + separator.Length) % stride != 0)
    {
        throw new FormatException();
    }

    var bytes = new byte[(str.Length + separator.Length) / stride];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < str.Length; i += stride)
    {
        bytes[j] = byte.Parse(str.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        j++;

        // There is no separator at the end!
        if (j != bytes.Length && separator != string.Empty)
        {
            if (string.CompareOrdinal(str, i + 2, separator, 0, separator.Length) != 0)
            {
                throw new FormatException();
            }
        }
    }

    return bytes;
}

public static string BytesToHex(byte[] bytes, string separator = " ")
{
    if (bytes == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    if (separator == null)
    {
        separator = string.Empty;
    }

    if (bytes.Length == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder((bytes.Length * (2 + separator.Length)) - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(separator);
        }

        sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

public static byte[] SimpleEncrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, CipherMode cipherMode, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] bytes)
{
    algorithm.Mode = cipherMode;
    algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    algorithm.Key = key;
    algorithm.IV = iv;

    using (var encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor())
    {
        return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}

public static byte[] SimpleDecrypt(SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, CipherMode cipherMode, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] bytes)
{
    algorithm.Mode = cipherMode;
    algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    algorithm.Key = key;
    algorithm.IV = iv;

    using (var encryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor())
    {
        return encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
string text = "xxxyyy";
string key = "da 39 a3 ee 5e 6b 4b 0d 32 55 bf ef 95 60 18 90";
string iv = "f8 01 8b 76 7c db 80 9c ed 66 fd 63 e8 41 d6 04";

var encrypted = BytesToHex(
    SimpleEncrypt(
        new RijndaelManaged(), 
        CipherMode.CBC, 
        HexToBytes(key), 
        HexToBytes(iv),
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));

var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
    SimpleDecrypt(
        new RijndaelManaged(), 
        CipherMode.CBC, 
        HexToBytes(key), 
        HexToBytes(iv),
        HexToBytes(encrypted))).TrimEnd('\0');
```

Note that that page **isn't good for binary data**, because it uses `Padding.Zeros`. The problem is that the plaintext composed of these bytes:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
```

is transformed to

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

before encryption, because it is padded to 16 characters. This operation can't be reversed. The `PaddingMode.PKCS7` you were using is better, because it can be reversed, but isn't compatible with that page! If you work on encrypting strings, this isn't a problem, because you can do a `TrimEnd('\0')` and remove the excess `\0`. You can check it by taking a small zip file that hasn't the size divisible by 16, encrypting it through the page ("input type" select File), then pressing Encrypt, then pressing Download as binary file. Then pressing Browse, selecting the file you just downloaded, pressing Decrypt, pressing Download as binary file. The file size will be different from the original file, but you will still be able to open it with zip.