# How to initialize an array to 0 without using for loops in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array called `Buffer`. I am using a for loop to initialize its contents to `0`. How do I do it in a single statement in C#? I do not want to use the for-loop.

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[50];
int arrC = 0;
// array initialization
for (arrC = 0; arrC < 50; arrC++)
{
    Buffer[arrC] = 0;
}
```

Comment: The array is already initialized to 0 as the `default(byte)` is `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C# what is the default value of the bytes when creating a new byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506274/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-default-value-of-the-bytes-when-creating-a-new-byte-array)

Answer (score 12):

You don't, and you don't have to. The default value for a `byte` is `0`.

Hence, if you create an array of type `byte[]`, each item in the array has the default value `0`.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is correct. If you have a better answer, please post it.

Answer (score -2):

When you have an array of `byte` that has some values, and then you want to replace its whole items to `0` a way is:

```
buffer = new byte[buffer.Length];
```

or

```
buffer = buffer.Select(c => (byte)0).ToArray();
```

or - as commented by @Matthew Watson - and I think is the best for setting items of an array to its default

```
Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Your answer seems to miss the point that it's about the initial values, not about replacing the existing values in an array. However, your LINQ suggestion is a working solution for the OP in case he wants to initialise with **non-default** values.

Comment: I think and hope, OP wants to replace items of an existing array to `0` ;).

Comment: Well if the OP wanted to set existing elements to zero, they should use [`Array.Clear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks I added your way to the answer, If you are not agree with that I'll remove it - and upvote your answer ;).